# ValidationMessageFor not showing errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this class:

```
public class Product
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "empty name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "empty description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a ResponseProduct which is shown in view:

```
public class ProductInsertVM
{
    public string Message = "Success";
    public Product Product;
}
```

In my view I have this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){  
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Product.Description)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Product.Description)
}
```

What I want to know is why ValidationMessageFor doest'n work? !! only ValidationSummary works. If I respond with a Product, so it works.

Comment: Try to put `Required` attributes in a View Model directly. Create a new class which is same as `Product` and use it as the Model in the view. It is a correct practice to use a simple View Model for every View which contains just the fields from the form or the fields to display.

Comment: Do you mean a class with the sames properties and same data annotations? isn't bad?

Comment: `ProductInsertViewModel` for example, should contain all the fields you will need: `Name`, `Description`, and that's it. You can actually use `Product` for that. Just don't use `ResponseProductInsert`. For the `Message` value, the proper way would be to use resources. Create a `Resources_local` special folder, set it to generate code, and use the string values from the resources in your code directly. With resources you will localize easier if needed.

Comment: I wasn't sure this would be a solution, but I did describe a good practice :). If Shyju's answer helps, treat what I wrote just as an advice for the future.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The code you provided should work fine if the following conditions are met.

**1)** You have reference to the jQuery validation scripts in your view

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**2)** On the form submit, you are calling the ModelState.IsValid property and hence validating the model passed to the action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CarList(CarList model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       //Save or whatever you want to do 
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Well, I am doing these tips, so that if I use just Product model in view, it works. But if I use ProductInsertVM.Product.Description, it doesn't.

Comment: @murilokunze: But in your question you showed ResponseProductInsert. Not ProductInserVM !

Comment: Yes, sorry.. I just changed the name for better understanding;

Answer (score 1):

Was missing this line in the _Lahout.cshtml

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

Complete:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") <------------ 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```